# If $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k} < + \infty$, then $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k \to 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm currently reading a paper, where they assert that for a nonnegative sequence $a_k$ of real numbers with $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k} < + \infty$, we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k = 0$.

My attempt to prove this was using the following idea: If $a_k > \varepsilon > 0$ for all $k \geq k_0$, then $$ \sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k} > \varepsilon \sum_{k = k_0}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = + \infty.$$

So we should have some decay condition on the $a_k$. However, we could have $a_k$ to be the characteristic function of $\{ n^2 : n \geq 1 \}$ for instance; then we can't compare the series $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{k}$ to the harmonic numbers; but then we can equally deduce the fact since square numbers have density zero.

I know that this is very vague. The reason for this is, that I couldn't get the idea to work.

How can I prove the fact?

Thanks!

Comment: Just for reference, this and its generalization is often called as [*Kronecker's lemma*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker%27s_lemma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Define
$$
S:=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{k},
$$
and
$$
S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{k}.
$$
Then $S_n\to S$ as $n\to\infty$; so, we can choose $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $\lvert S_n-S\rvert<\epsilon$.

Now, for a given $n> N$, write
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{a_k}{n}+\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{n}.
$$
You can bound the second term by
$$
0\leq\sum_{k=N+1}^n\frac{a_k}{n}\leq\sum_{k=N+1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{k}\leq\sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{k}=S-S_N<\epsilon.
$$
Can you see how to make the first term small as well?